# GRUB skipped sometimes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Dell xps 15 inch 9570.  Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1.  I noticed that when I reboot with one external USB drive (WDBook 3T, 3 NTFS partitions and 1 ext4 partition) plugged in, the computer skips GRUB and boot directly to Windows 10.  If I unplug the ext USB drive, reboot goes normally to GRUB.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like there is a bootloader installed on the external drive, though I'm not sure how to fix it. The least effort solution might be to rearrange your boot options in the firmware settings.

Comment: I'm not sure how to rearrange boot options, though.  My work around is unplug the usb if I need to boot to ubuntu and plug it back in after booted.  But a permanent solution is certainly appreciated.

Comment: This might be useful: [How to get rid of grub boot loader from external HDD - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1335236/443564)